# The sum which gives $3^n$

Tags: proof-writing, multinomial-coefficients

So I have the following which I must prove :

$$\sum_{(n_1,n_2,n_3)\,:\,n_1+n_2+n_3=n}  \binom{n}{n_1, n_2, n_3}  = 3^n$$

I'm not sure where I must begin. This is a multinomial.

Comment: How about the multinomial theorem, for $(1+1+1)^n$?

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't think about that. I just learned this stuff, I'm very sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the multinomial theorem as suggested by Carl Heckman or you can think the equality as two different ways to represent the following combination:

Suppose you have $n$ objects and you want to assign them to three clusters. Both the RHS and LHS are the total number of assignments that you can made.

Comment: I have set up (x+y+z)^n=3^n and put x=y=z=1 is this good ?

Comment: @Astroman I don't understand what you mean by "set up (x+y+z)^n=3^n$. See Multinomial theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem), then set $m=3,x_1=x_2=x_3=1$, it will give you the result you want.

Comment: Wait is it this simple ? It seems like I just have to replace the numbers that you suggested to get what I want...

Comment: @Astroman It depends on your background. If you haven't learn multinomial theorem, maybe you have to prove it before using it.